# How to configure JBoss AS 7 to log to syslog?

Tags: jboss, syslog, rsyslog

How do i configure jboss to log to syslog?

Answer (score 1):

Putting something like:

```
 <!-- Syslog events -->  <appender name="SYSLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">  <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>  <param name="Facility" value="LOCAL7"/>  <param name="FacilityPrinting" value="true"/>  <param name="SyslogHost" value="localhost"/>  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE},%c{1}] %m%n"/>  </layout>  </appender>
```

in your log4j.conf would work... Just make sure to tune it down to what you actually want, just uses standard log4j context, you definitely wouldn't want all of your jvm logs to be spitting out to syslog in most app server configs...

Comment: where do i put log4j.conf? there isn't one by default in jboss 7 =/

Comment: See this link: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Logging

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:
https://github.com/kifj/jboss-syslog

```
     <profile>
         <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.2">
+               <custom-handler name="SYSLOG" class="x1.jboss.syslog.SyslogHandler"     module="x1.jboss-syslog">
+                       <level name="INFO"/>
+                       <properties>
+                           <property name="loghost" value="localhost"/>
+                           <property name="application" value="jboss-as7"/>
+                       </properties>
+               </custom-handler>
             <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                 <level name="INFO"/>
                 <formatter>
@@ -89,8 +100,7 @@
             <root-logger>
                 <level name="INFO"/>
                 <handlers>
-                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
-                    <handler name="FILE"/>
+                    <handler name="SYSLOG"/>
                 </handlers>
             </root-logger>
         </subsystem>
```

for access log it still does not work.
the  tag wants to write to file, and have no idea how to use a custom logger there.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Serverfault! Please read the [How to Answer a Question Guide](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-answer). This site is a Q&A site not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS 7.2 has syslog handler, so you can use:

```
<syslog-handler name="SYSLOG">
    <level name="DEBUG" />
    <server-address value="<syslog.server>"/>
    <port value="<syslog.port>"/>
</syslog-handler>

...

<root-logger>
    <handlers>
    ...
        <handler name="SYSLOG" />
    ...
    </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

More info in documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-sysloghandler